# Magento 2.1: display a search bar in your website's header

Tags: magento-2.1, search, catalogsearch

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop. To achieve this, I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**.

I have moved the **top links** at the right of the logo:

```
<move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
```

I want to display the *search bar* (it does not display *anywhere*) above the top links (like the screenshot indicates).

[image]

For this purpose, I wrote the line below, in my `default.xml` file:

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="links" />
```

The result is that the search bar not only does not display above the top links but *it does not display at all*.

There is alse a `app/design/frontend/Company_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Search/layout/default.xml` file with this code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="top.search" destination="navbar-collapse" after="navigation.sections" />
        <referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

As you can see, on the **[website's homepage](https://staging.pro-detailing.ro/)**, the search box does not appear anywhere.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Could the search feature be disabled from admin?
3. Can I display the search bar inside the top links `<ul>` element?

Comment: if it is not displaying , first check in the code if it is removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following code sequence in my custom theme's `default.xml` file:

```
<container name="header.main.search" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header-search" after="-">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
</container>
<move element="header.main.search" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
<move element="top.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="header.main.search" />
```

The code above renders the following HTML in the page source:

```
<div class="header content">
  <strong class="logo">
   <img src="https://dev3.pro-detailing.ro/pub/static/version1516374892/frontend/ProDetailing/v1/en_US/images/logo.png" alt="Magento Commerce" width="263" height="85">
  </strong>
  <div class="header-search">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" id="search_mini_form" action="https://dev3.pro-detailing.ro/catalogsearch/result/" method="get">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="q" value="" placeholder="Search entire store here..." class="form-control" maxlength="128" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="false" aria-autocomplete="both" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" disabled="">Search</button>
      <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete" style="display: none;"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-inline clearfix header links">
    <li><a href="https://dev3.pro-detailing.ro/customer/account/">My Account</a></li>
    <li class="authorization-link" data-label="or">
      <a href="https://dev3.pro-detailing.ro/customer/account/login/">
      Sign In</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Change This :

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="links" />
```

To:

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="header.links"/>
```

OR

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="top.links"/>
```

Comment: I tried it. It does not work.

Comment: Please check if it is adding in html code or not in view source? Please Check Updates.

Comment: It is not in the page source either.

Comment: <move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="top.links"/> Try this !!

Answer (score 0):

If your parent theme is a Blank theme. Use this code

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="top.links"/>
```

If Your parent theme is a Luma theme, then use this

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header-wrapper" before="header.links"/>
```

Comment: I tried it. It does not work.

Comment: clear your cache and check again. It's working on my side.

Comment: Check this screenshot  https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQltk.png

Comment: Could it be disabled from admin? How do I enable it?

Comment: If you cache is disabled, then you don't need to refresh the cache. The result should be rendered. Check if your layout is overwritten somewhere.

Comment: I meant the search bar _not_ the cache.

Comment: You seem to be very knowledgeable of Magento. Please have a look at **[this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208650/assign-all-products-in-a-category-to-all-its-ancestor-categories-automatically)** too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<!-- ... other block of code -->
<filterSearch name="fulltext">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing.mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing_data_source</item>
<item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing.mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
<item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing.mageplaza_helloworld_post_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
<item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
</item>
</item>
</argument>
</filterSearch>
<!-- ... other block of code -->
</listing>
```

Comment: In what file shall I put the code above? And _where_ in that respective file?

Comment: you can find all sample grid examples from this location : C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\ui_component\etc\definition.xml:

Comment: there i use this code : C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Mastering\SampleModule\view\adminhtml\ui_component\mastering_items_grid.xml

Comment: That is your _local_ server.

Comment: yes ofcourse it is