# Assign all products in a category to all it's ancestor categories programmatically, in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, category-products

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop and I have created a **child-theme of Magento Blank**

The products are organized into *categories and subcategories*. In other words, they are organized into *parent categories* and *children categories*.

Whenever a product is assigned, through the *Magento admin*, to a child category, I want it to be automatically assigned to all the ancestor categories of that child category.

[image: The Footwear category tree]

I want to manually assign all the boot brands in the store to the "Boots" child category add I want all boots to be **automatically** put, by Magento, in the "Footwear" parent category.

**Question:** What is the *programming* solution that would do the job, *recursively*?

Comment: did you find a code solution  to this? I have the saem issue and I'd like to assign parent categories to products programmatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple solution which Magento 2.x provides by default.

- Go to **Products > Categories**.
- Click on the (parent) category in which you want to show the products of the sub-category.
- Under **Display Settings**, set **`Yes`** for **Anchor** field.
- Save the category, flush Magento's cache and reindex.

Please let me know if the solution works for you.

Comment: How do I _reindex_?

Comment: in the root of your Magento instance run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` but I would run the following command to reindex and clear cache: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex && bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: It does work, in principle, but in practice, there is a problem. I have: *Home >  Intretinere Exterior >  Spalare & Detailing Rapid >  Spuma Prespalare & Sampon Auto* (the site's bradcrumbs). *Intretinere Exterior* shows products, but NOT *Spalare & Detailing Rapid*.

Comment: @Mohit Kumar Arora: It does work, but I'd rather not do repetitive operations from the admin, by hand. I am looking for a **code solution**. Thanks a lot for the effort *and* the very useful tip :)

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, why have you unaccepted the solution??

Comment: @Mohit Kumar Arora,  It is a pretty good solution, I will accept it again if I don't get a *programming* solution like I mentioned I needed (please look at the comments above this one). Until the BOUNTY expires, I will keep the current answer "unaccepted", so that new answers are encouraged.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora If i run sales report based sql query products list low compare than subcategory list. Parent category given 10, sub category given 50. I have enabled anchor "Yes". I am using magento 1.9. How to assign subcategories of product assign to parent category.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Your solution just for the front end if we take reports from SQL, products not mapped with parent category. How to handle this issue?